# Android studio NPE when passing bundle

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I want to receive string from another activity. But it gave me an NPE.

MainActivity.class

```
private void searchProcess(final String searchPhone) {
    String tag_string_req = "req_search";
    Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DbActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("searchPhone", searchPhone);
    i2.putExtras(bundle);
    i2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(i2);
    Log.d(TAG, "SENDING NUMBER FROM MAIN ACTIVITY: " + searchPhone);

}
```

DbActivity.class

```
Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle1 !=null) {
            final String searchPhone = bundle1.get("searchPhone").toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "RECEIVING NUMBER FROM MainActivity: " + searchPhone);
```

and this error comes up

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
at site.mobilesocial.google.DbActivity.onCreate(DbActivity.java:156)
```

and line 156 is

```
final String searchPhone = bundle1.get("searchPhone").toString();
```

help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `searchPhone` is null when you put into Bundle ,you would get null by `bundle1.get("searchPhone")`. So you should do as following code :

```
String searchPhoneReceived = bundle1.get("searchPhone");
if (searchPhoneReceived != null) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using .getStringExtra() in DbActivity.class?

Comment: cannot resolve method getStringExtra()

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I was trying to convert null object to string. Found a solution thanks.

```
Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle1 !=null) {
            final Object searchPhone = bundle1.get("searchPhone");
            //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
            if (isNull(searchPhone)){

            } else {
               final String searchPhone1 = searchPhone.toString();
               extranumber.setText(searchPhone1);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "RECEIVING NUMBER FROM MAIN ACTIVITY: " + searchPhone);
        }
```